# Sum of cells within a given range of dates

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to calculate my revenues in a given trimester, based on the invoice total and the date it was paid.

```
Column B - invoices to add up
Column E - date paid
```

Here is my attempt (which comes up with an error):

```
=sumifs(Paiement!B2:B100; Paiement!E2:E100; "=>01/01/2014", "<01/04/2014")
```

Any ideas? Sorry if this has been answered already, but I couldn't seem to get formulas in other answers to work when I applied them to my case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close: the only mistake is not stating the range to which the second criterion is to be applied. Recall the syntax of [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en):

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])
```

So, you need

```
=sumifs(Paiement!B2:B100; Paiement!E2:E100; ">=01/01/2014"; Paiement!E2:E100; "<01/04/2014")
```

(You may think it's *obvious* that the second criterion is also to be applied to the same E column, but it's not obvious to the software.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so clearly, it worked!
Small correction (my mistake), it should be ">=" and not "=>"